# Can any cricket player play for any other team without nationality of this country?

Tags: cricket

I saw many cricketers which play for another country instead of his own country.But  is it necessary to get nationality of this country for playing international cricket  for this country?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include some examples of what you're referring to?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. There aren't that many cricketers that don't play for their country of birth and if they don't, they will always meet some eligibility requirement. Eoin Morgan is a good example and one that has played for both Ireland and England. Mark Chapman, who has played for both Hong Kong and New Zealand, holds dual citizenship for those countries.

Answer (score 1):

Cricketers who play for other countries are most likely born and raised in that country. For example, Hashim Amla is an Indian by origin, but was raised in South Africa and gained nationality of South Africa. Thus, he is in the national team. If any player does not have a nationality of the country they wish to play for, then they most probably aren't able to.